# Get retrieve XML attrib using ElementTree Python

Tags: xml, python-3.x, xml-parsing, elementtree

I am trying to get an elements attribute but all I am getting is a None value or empty list depending on what I try to get it. Also if anyone knows a better way to get the particular tag for the element I would appreciate it.
Here is the code and the spaced out part is what should return the url but doesnt.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import webbrowser,time,urllib.request
import tkinter as tk
import urllib

# webbrowser.get('windows-default').open_new('http://www.reddit.com/'+'r/blender')
main = tk.Tk()
class Application(tk.Frame):



    def __init__(self, master=None):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack()
        self.createWidgets()
        self.initial()

    def createWidgets(self):
        # print('Went to createWidgets()')
        self.send_entry = tk.Entry(self)
        self.send_entry.grid(row=0,column=0)
        self.change_sub = tk.Button(self,text='Change Subreddit', command=lambda :self.getXML(self.send_entry.get())).grid(row=0 , column=2)
        self.lb_scrollY = tk.Scrollbar(self,orient=tk.VERTICAL)
        self.lb_scrollY.grid(row=1,column=1,sticky=tk.NS)
        self.thread_lb = tk.Listbox(self,yscrollcommand=self.lb_scrollY.set)
        self.lb_scrollY['command']=self.thread_lb.yview
        self.thread_lb.grid(row=1,column=0)
        self.QUIT = tk.Button(self, text="QUIT", fg="red", command=main.destroy).grid(row=2)




    def descStripper(self,desc):
        x1=int(desc.find('alt="'))
        if x1 != -1:
            x2Start = x1+5
            x2=int(desc.find('"',x2Start))
            desc = desc[x1+5:x2]
            return desc
        else:
            desc = "There is no description. Maybe it's a link"
            return desc

    def lbPopulator(self,title,pub,link):
        # print('Went to lbPopulator()')
        self.thread_lb.delete(0,tk.END)
        for item in title:
            self.thread_lb.insert(tk.END,item)

    def getXmlData(self):
        counter = 0
        self.threadPubDateList = []
        self.threadTitleList = []
        self.threadLinkList = []
        self.threadDescList = []
        self.threadThumbNail = []
        tree=ET.parse('rss.xml')
        root=tree.getroot()
        for channel in root:
            for SubChannel in channel:
                if SubChannel.tag == 'item':
                    for threadInfo in SubChannel:
                        # print(SubChannel.getchildren())
                        if threadInfo.tag == 'title':
                            self.threadTitleList.append(threadInfo.text)
                        if threadInfo.tag == 'pubDate':
                            self.threadPubDateList.append(threadInfo.text[:-6])
                        if threadInfo.tag == 'link':
                            self.threadLinkList.append(threadInfo.text)
                        if threadInfo.tag == 'description':
                            self.threadDescList.append(self.descStripper(threadInfo.text))









                        if threadInfo.tag == '{http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/}title':
                            print(threadInfo.tag)
                            print(threadInfo.attrib)
                            print(threadInfo.get('url'))











        self.lbPopulator(self.threadTitleList,self.threadPubDateList,self.threadLinkList)
        # print(self.threadTitleList)
        # print(self.threadPubDateList)
        # print(self.threadLinkList)
        # print(self.threadDescList)
    def getXML(self,subreddit):
        try:
            url = 'http://www.reddit.com'+subreddit+'.rss'
            source = urllib.request.urlretrieve(url,'rss.xml')
            self.getXmlData()
        except urllib.error.HTTPError as err:
            print('Too many requests-Try again')
    def initial(self):
        try:
            source = urllib.request.urlretrieve('http://www.reddit.com/.rss','rss.xml')
            self.getXmlData()
        except urllib.error.HTTPError as err:
            print('Too many requests-Trying again 3')
            time.sleep(3)
            self.__init__()


# main.geometry("250x150")

app = Application(master=main)
app.mainloop()
```

Here is a the bit of the code that should be returning a url of thumbnail when passed a XML file. It is all the last 'if' statement and the rest all work fine.

```
def getXmlData(self):
    counter = 0
    self.threadPubDateList = []
    self.threadTitleList = []
    self.threadLinkList = []
    self.threadDescList = []
    self.threadThumbNail = []
    tree=ET.parse('rss.xml')
    root=tree.getroot()
    for channel in root:
        for SubChannel in channel:
            if SubChannel.tag == 'item':
                for threadInfo in SubChannel:
                    # print(SubChannel.getchildren())
                    if threadInfo.tag == 'title':
                        self.threadTitleList.append(threadInfo.text)
                    if threadInfo.tag == 'pubDate':
                        self.threadPubDateList.append(threadInfo.text[:-6])
                    if threadInfo.tag == 'link':
                        self.threadLinkList.append(threadInfo.text)
                    if threadInfo.tag == 'description':
                        self.threadDescList.append(self.descStripper(threadInfo.text))
                    if threadInfo.tag == '{http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/}title':
                        print(threadInfo.tag)
                        print(threadInfo.attrib)
                        print(threadInfo.get('url'))
```

Comment: You should try posting a specific bit of your code that exemplifies your issue, or create an illustrative example. It would also be helpful to see a sample input, expected output, and actual output.

Comment: That is better. It makes it easier to see what you tried and what went wrong. It would be also good to see an example of the XML element you are parsing... What is the output of the 3 `print` statements in the final `if` block?

Comment: If you just run the program it will download the XML. You can find it at [reddit.com/.rss](http://reddit.com/.rss) 

Out put is 

`{http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/}title'`
`{}`
`None`

Comment: I believe that it should be returning      `'{http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/}title'`       `'url':'(thumbnailURL)'`       `(thumbnailURL)`

Comment: There is no XML tag in that page called "{http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/}title". Do you mean to put `if threadInfo.tag == 'title'`?

Comment: At the beginning of the XML file xmlns:media is declared as "{http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/}". Without substituting it, it never finds the element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only tag that has an attribute called *url* is the *media:thumbnail* tag. And as you pointed out, `media` is declared at the top with `xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/"`. This leads me to believe that your last if statement should be:

```
if threadInfo.tag == '{http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/}thumbnail':
   print(threadInfo.tag)
   print(threadInfo.attrib)
   print(threadInfo.get('url'))
```

Which should produce the output:

```
'{http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/}thumbnail'
{'url' : 'http://a.thumbs.redditmedia.com/cozEqqG9muj-tT3Z.jpg'}
'http://a.thumbs.redditmedia.com/cozEqqG9muj-tT3Z.jpg'
```

Comment: At the beginning of the xml media is declared as {http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/}. If you change it to the "media:thumbnail" then it never finds the tag.

Comment: Yup that works. Didn't remember to change it back to thumbnail. Thank you!